# Android Realm: how to search string is either null or empty

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a very quick question. How to get all records where the particular field (*String type*) is not **null** and **empty**.

Currently, I do:

```
String nullStr = null; //temporary null string to pass it to realm.

RealmResults<Feedback> feedbacks = realm.where(Feedback.class)
                .notEqualTo("Comment", nullStr)
                .notEqualTo("Comment", "")
                .findAll();
```

Is this the only way to get record that is not null and empty? How about if the **Comment** contains only spaces? Is there a way to get record where the field is not null and not contain white-spaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
  realm.where(Feedback.class)
            .isNull("Comment")
            .or()
            .equalTo("Comment", "")
            .findAll();
```

And if you want the inverse of this, use `not().beginGroup()./*query here*/.endGroup()`

Comment: Is it possible to check if the field contain only space?

Comment: I can't really think of a way to do that, I'd just store a string that I called `trim()` on before saving.

Comment: Thank you3x so much you save my day. I forgot to read the doc how to filter  null value until i read your post thank you